# I forgot exactly location of my folder. What to do now? Is there any command to do this?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Windows:    7 ultimate
System type:    64-bit operating system

Let me describe that I hid a folder using command prompt some months ago. Now I have forgotten the location of folder though I remember half location I mean I know the directory and folder of my hidden folder but the problem is I forgot subfolder name that create the problem to unhide it using command prompt.

Please someone help me how to unhide it.

Comment: Post in Super User, not here.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your hidden folder is on the C: drive, and the name is "hiddenFolder":

```
dir /b /s /aHD "c:\hiddenFolder"
```

It may take a while, but eventually it will find it. You can press `<Ctrl-C>` to abort once the folder is found.

Once you find the folder, you can then type into the command prompt this command to unset the "Hidden" attribute:

```
attrib -H <full-path-to-folder>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could mount the drive in a linux or unix based OS and find the path as it no longer would be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to be simple enough. Just ensure hidden files/folders are visible in Explorer via `Tools menu / Folder Options / View tab`. Then locate the hidden folder (the icon will be more faded out than the rest, else add the `Attributes` column to the `Details` view). Once you've found it, unhide it via right-click / Properties and if need be reset the Show hidden files/folders option. There, that should do it!

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple.... Just open folder option.... Go to view tab... There.. Enable to show hidden files...... Also untick the option saying dont show system protected files... Now go to the directory of that folder... You will find it.... Right click on that folder.... Then open folder options... There deselect the hidden option......... U r done..... Dont forget to deselect the option saying dont show system protected files in folder option.... It is the most important part of this easy process